# View all community wiki questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, tag-wiki

Community wiki Q&A is a mystery to me, but still, I would like to see all questions that were converted to it.

I know some sites actually tag these questions with a [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) but I think a more holistic approach is needed here.

Viewing all CW in a single view will also allow to manage it in a better way. (edit/clean/merge/delete/...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to tag CW questions. We have a search flag for that. Put

```
wiki:yes
```

in the search box to view all CW posts.

Besides using the way you suggest would only find CW questions and not answers.

Comment: ... and you can add `is:q` or `is:a` to filter as questions or answers, if this is desired.